# Databases from 2 SharePoint servers on the same database server?

Tags: wss-3.0, database, infrastructure

I've got 3 servers:
 - DB1
 - SharePoint1
 - SharePoint2

On SharePoint1 I've installed WSS, using DB1 as database. 
Now I want to install WSS onto SharePoint2 and use DB1 as database storage as well.

My question is: Does it conflict to have the databases from two SharePoint installations located on the same instance of the same SQL server?

The two SharePoint installations have nothing in common except they use the same SQL server (both not the same databases, of course). I can't create a new instance on the SQL server...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can share the same database server in your scenario.

Are you buildning a new farm?

Make sure to rename your configuration database, during the installation, from the default one, so it differs from the one already there.

/WW

Comment: Yes, I'm building a new farm. Completely independant from the first SharePoint farm. 
So, my new installation won't overwrite any of the databases of the already existing installation?

Comment: The SharePoint installer will prohibit you from overwriting the config db, since it contains info. It only allows using pre-created db's if they are empty.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are have different names for Sharepoint_Config database. It shouldnt get conflicted.

Answer (score 0):

Concur with everything above, but do remember that SharePoint is all about SQL Server for performance, watch all SharePoint Databases closely.  As a general rule for any high band (say > 100 users Simultaneously on) SharePoint site, I typically dedicate the SQL Server to SharePoint.